# SQL query over two column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables as follows,

Table name `Payment_transaction` having column name as

```
payment_ref_id, booking_ref_id, amount, due_date
```

second table is named as `booking` having cloumn name as `booking_ref_id, date_created booking_status`

I want to write a query which will return number of payment transaction per year.

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i am confused about how to group transaction over year. Since I have number of transaction for same year (date_created) so how to sort out this.

Comment: -1. Is it mysql or sql? The tags suggests its a SQL Server related. if true, remove mysql. few solutions are very specific, especially when it comes to tsql  and functions. May be you have doubted whether you can use functions in the group by clause or not, you should try it, figure out what is the function which gives the year part from the date and just add it in the group by clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(p.booking_ref_id) AS payment_count,
    YEAR(b.date_created) AS payment_year
FROM booking b
INNER JOIN Payment_transaction p
    ON p.booking_ref_id = b.booking_ref_id
GROUP BY YEAR(b.date_created)
```

Comment: I'll give you an upvote when you add the `GROUP BY YEAR(b.date_created)` :-)

Comment: Ok, now you can have my upvote ;-)

Comment: thank all of you it worked .... after using GROUP BY YEAR(b.date_created)

Answer (score 1):

If all transactions are saved in `Payment_transaction` then there is no need for the booking table if you want to count the payment_transactions not the bookings per transaction.

Query should look like this:

```
SELECT Year(due_date), COUNT(*) 
FROM Payment_transaction
GROUP BY Year(due_date)
```

Comment: transaction  are saved in Booking table.